# After drawing instanced arrays, what is the procedure for executing a regular draw operation?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I wrote some WebGL2 code to render a few thousand circles using drawArraysInstanced. I'm using code from https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html.

I also have a fullscreen quad to display a more appealing background than black. Both work independently, but rendering the instanced array of circles disrupts the background rendering.

I suspect I should unbind or unset something after rendering the circles, but I can't tell what. The problem is that the webgl2 fundamentals example doesn't specify what has to happen every frame and what has to happen once, and it doesn't attempt to render anything but the instanced arrays.

How can I clean the webgl2 state after rendering the instanced arrays so that regular rendering works again?

https://jsfiddle.net/g2xkoc56/

```
gl.useProgram(shader);
    gl.uniform4fv(colorUniform, color);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(viewProjectionMatrixUniform, false, viewProjectionMatrix);

    bindIndexBuffer(gl, indexBuffer);

    // upload the new matrix data
    for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      const offset = i * 16;
      mat4.fromTranslation(matrixData.subarray(offset, offset + 16), positions[i]);
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, matrixBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, matrixData);

    const bytesPerMatrix = 4 * 16;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      const loc = matrixAttribute + i;
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc);
      // note the stride and offset
      const offset = i * 16;  // 4 floats per row, 4 bytes per float
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        loc,              // location
        4,                // size (num values to pull from buffer per iteration)
        gl.FLOAT,    // type of data in buffer
        false,            // normalize
        bytesPerMatrix,   // stride, num bytes to advance to get to next set of values
        offset,           // offset in buffer
      );
      // this line says this attribute only changes for each 1 instance
      gl.vertexAttribDivisor(loc, 1);
    }

    bindVertexBuffer(gl, vertexPositionAttribute, vertexBuffer, 3);
    bindIndexBuffer(gl, indexBuffer);
    gl.drawArraysInstanced(
      gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, // GL Fan, strip, etc.
      0,       // offset
      sides+2, // num vertices per instance
      count,   // num instances
    );
    unbindIndexBuffer(gl);
    unbindVertexBuffer(gl, vertexPositionAttribute);
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      gl.disableVertexAttribArray(matrixAttribute + i);
    }
```

Screenshots:
[image: before particles run, background is visible]
[image: after particles render, background is still visible]
[image: Rerendering background doesn't work:]

Comment: Where are the [Vertex Array Objects](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.6)?

Comment: Generally, every frame should start rendering from the beginning, from a clean slate (clear canvas). Does https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-animation.html help?

Comment: @Bergi, that page only seems to talk about using requestAnimationFrame. The background quad renders every frame just fine if I haven't tried to run the instanced calls. Every frame clears the zbuffer and the frame to black. Then the background object tries to render, but it fails if the instanced arrays code is run in the previous frame.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks, I updated the sample. The vertex array object is a bunch of vertices to draw a single circle around 0,0.
```
const type = this.gl.FLOAT;
const normalize = false;
const stride = 0;
const offset = 0;
this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vertexPositionAttribute, this.width, type, normalize, stride, offset);
this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexPositionAttribute);
```

Comment: @whiterook6 What does "it fails" mean? In your code, what part runs every frame and what part runs once for initialisation? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Bergi done. I was dragging my feat but I unrefactored all my code into smaller example.

Comment: Thanks! I must say it just works for me… what exactly is the problem? I've added `positions` animation [here](https://jsfiddle.net/608c5znd/)

Comment: @Bergi The background is only visible for a single frame, after which it disappears and is replaced with black. If you comment out drawing the particles during the loop, it is a pleasant pastel background color.

Comment: Weird. I get the pink background and the blue particles in every animation frame. At least on `Ubuntu/22.04 x86_64; X11; Chromium/116.0.0.0`. Quite possible that the WebGl/OpenGL implementation is a different than yours. Whether this is a bug in your code or in your Browser/WebGL/OS (or in mine) I cannot tell. I might investigate the code in more detail later.

Comment: @Bergi the Webgl fundamentals author responded to my comments and I learned it was because I wasn't clearing the vertex attrib divisors properly. I'll "answer my own question" promptly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't clearing the vertex attrib divisor for the instanced matrices properly after rendering the instanced particles, which was preventing the background from rendering next frame. (Though some people didn't have an issue with the same code, so maybe it was something else.)

After rendering the particles, before the break between frames:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(matrixAttribute + i, 0);
}
```